# How to speed up the check for duplicate rows when using the Python library dataset?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, duplicates, dataset

How can the is_duplicate_free(table) function change, so it runs significantly faster? It performs poorly on life-sized tables. Currently, the following test program takes 45 seconds on my workstation.

I know faster ways on some specific database engines, but despite rereading the documentation [https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/] and googling, I can't find a database-agnostic speed-up for the dataset library.

```
import dataset      # https://dataset.readthedocs.io
import random
import string
import time

def is_duplicate_free(table) -> bool:
    """ Is the table free of duplicates, True or False? """
    # TODO Speed up; perhaps use the database engine to count.
    # TODO With the dataset library currently, we use SQLite and PostgreSQL, ideally, remain database agnostic.
    # TODO Be compatible with current versions of Python 3.
    count = 0
    columns = table.columns
    columns.remove('id')    # Ignore the automatic serial id. TODO Also, cope none or some other primary key.
    for _row in table.distinct(*columns):
        count += 1
    return count == len(table)


def main() -> None:
    start_time = time.time()

    db = dataset.connect(f"sqlite:///database.db")

    # create a table or clear it if it already exists
    table = db.create_table('table')
    columns = [*string.ascii_lowercase]
    table.delete()
    assert is_duplicate_free(table)

    # insert unique rows
    row = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(len(columns))]
    for _ in range(1000):
        row[random.randint(0, len(columns) - 1)] += 1
        table.insert(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        assert is_duplicate_free(table)

    # insert a duplicate row
    table.insert(dict(zip(columns, row)))
    assert not is_duplicate_free(table)

    # insert more unique rows
    row = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(len(columns))]
    for _ in range(500):
        row[random.randint(0, len(columns) - 1)] += 1
        table.insert(dict(zip(columns, row)))
        assert not is_duplicate_free(table)

    db.close()

    print (f"elapsed time: {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```